# JS Promises - way to make this promise nesting more efficient?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, promise, angular-promise

Consider this piece of code:

```
WordPress.getMediaById(res.data.featured_media)
.then(function (res) {
  post.featuredMedia = res.data.source_url;

  WordPress.getUserById(post.authorId)
    .then(function (res) {
      post.authorName = res.data.name;

      $scope.post = {
        title: post.title,
        introAsHtml: post.introAsHtml,
        authorName: post.authorName,
        contentAsHtml: post.contentAsHtml,
        featured_media: post.featuredMedia
      };
    });
});
```

Is there any way to make it more efficient in terms of nesting? In the future I will want to add more promised functions into it and I am not sure if it's the right way, otherwise, how does it really differ from callbacks...

Regards.

Comment: You always should `return` things from your functions - especially when they're asynchronous

Comment: Are you using Q or Angular promises?

Comment: @Bergi Hey, q promises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the second async request does not depend on the result of the first call I definitely would not nest the promises.

With the help of angular's `$q`, you can so this:

```
$q.all([
  WordPress.getMediaById(mediaId),
  WordPress.getUserById(userId)])
.then(response => {
  post.featuredMedia = response[0].data.source_url;
  post.authorName = response[1].data.name;
  $scope.post = {
    title: post.title,
    introAsHtml: post.introAsHtml,
    authorName: post.authorName,
    contentAsHtml: post.contentAsHtml,
    featured_media: post.featuredMedia
  };
});
```

Comment: OP tagged his question with Q, so you shouldn't use `$q` instead.

Comment: @Bergi you are right. but it's tagged with angular at first place and hence since he/she did not explicitly mentioned only using Q it is still a valid answer. Not to mention that Q has an equivalent solution.

Comment: I am actually using angular's $q. Thank you @webduvet. I also added angular and Ionic so I thought it's obvious.

Comment: @webduvet so cool solution, you can even use objects with keys instead of arrays. Changed this to the answer!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce the nesting like this:

```
WordPress.getMediaById(res.data.featured_media)
.then(function (res) {
    //res.data is media
  post.featuredMedia = res.data.source_url;

  return WordPress.getUserById(post.authorId);
}).then(function (res) {
    //res.data is user
  post.authorName = res.data.name;

  $scope.post = {
    title: post.title,
    introAsHtml: post.introAsHtml,
    authorName: post.authorName,
    contentAsHtml: post.contentAsHtml,
    featured_media: post.featuredMedia
  };
});
```

For more info and a clear explanation of promises, read [this](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) blog by Nolan Lawson

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: So if I return an execution of another function that returns a promise, I can immediately chain them with ".then"? Have I understood correctly?

Comment: @Ariel: You can shorten that to "If I return a promise from the `then` callback, …", but in general [yes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572)